# Is it possible to 'auto-declare' a parent class property for every child class?

Tags: php, oop, properties, spl-autoload-register

Suppose I've got a library class and an autoloader that includes any class that starts with `MyLibrary_` from the `classes` directory:

```
spl_autoload_register(
    function ($classname) {

        if(class_exists($classname)) return;

        if(strpos($classname, 'MyLibrary_') !== 0) return;

        //if such class exists, include it
        $class_file = __DIR__.'/classes/'.$classname.'.php';
        if(file_exists($class_file)){
            include $class_file;
        }
    }
);
if(!class_exists('Someprefix_MyLibrary')){
    class Someprefix_MyLibrary{}
}
$mylibrary = new Someprefix_MyLibrary;
```

Then, in the `/classes/strings.php` file there is a child class MyLibrary_strings:

```
class MyLibrary_strings extends Someprefix_MyLibrary{

   public punction __construct(){
       $this->strings = new self(); //not declared in parent class
   }

   //make first letter capital in a multi-byte string
    public function mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding){
        $firstChar = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $encoding);
        $then = mb_substr($string, 1, null, $encoding);
        return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
    }
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
$new_string = $mylibrary->strings->mb_ucfirst('somestring');
```

Unless I declare `public $strings` in parent class, my IDE warns me that a property has been declared dynamically, and in other child classes, the `strings` property will be marked as not found. What I want is to **automatically** include a parent property for each file that has been placed into the `classes` directory OR for every child class of `Someprefix_MyLibrary`, without having to manually declare every property.

Is it possible to do it, and how?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to accomplish with this design. Seems inherently broken. On constructiion the object instantiates another copy of itself, which is stored on a property (and of course, _that_ instance will hold yet another copy of itself, and so on ad infinitum).

Comment: How, in this case, could I use child classes as methods of parent class, so that they would be able to use methods of their parent and sibling classes, but not hardcoding said classes as methods? `$library = new Parent; $library->class->method();` seems to be a neat, easy to remember way to use my library

Comment: I think it's a broken way of creating a library. And would not work with the code you provide, where you are starting an infinite chain of self-instantiation. But I bow to your superior expertise, I'm sure you know better. Good luck. Bye!

Comment: @yivi I am just trying to understand. You know, the less a person knows, the more they think of themselves ) I understood what you said about infinite instances and why you say it's a broken way of creating a library.

Comment: Look into static methods - there's no reason to initialise each class each time you want to use a part of it that is static.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [__get](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) magic method in php like so.

In your parent class, add a `__get` method:

```
class Someprefix_MyLibrary{
 
    public function __get(string $name)
    {
        return $this->{$name} = null;
    }
}
```

And call any undeclared property you need for example in your child class:

```
class MyLibrary_strings extends  Someprefix_MyLibrary{
 
    public function undeclaredProperty(){
        return $this->string;
    }

}
```

---

Note: Thus, when calling any undeclared property, we will fall into the __get magic method, where we will declare it and return it.

Comment: Will this work? `public function __get(string $name){ include_once __DIR__."/classes/{$name}.php"; return $this->{$name} = new $name; }`

Comment: @Artem, Yes, sure. Try

Comment: @Artem Just to create an object, do not forget to include parentheses for arguments. `return $this->{$name} = new $name();`

Comment: Besides mentioning a magic getter (which is already mentioned in many questions, if one thought _that_ was the answer it would have been better to flag as a duplicate), this does nothing to address the (admitedly weird and not very clear) OP requirements about these "magic properties" existing for "every file I place on 'classes', or for every child of the parent class".

Comment: @yivi I guess to ask a perfect question, one has to know most of the answer.

Comment: @Artem to ask a decent question, on the other hand, one needs only to do some research and spend some time testing and thinking about what it entails.

Comment: @yivi This is an answer that covers the OP's needs. I don't see any problems.

Comment: Returning `$this->string` on ANY undeclared property doesn't seem like a good idea. In fact this code doesn't even seem to work

Comment: @Rylee Don't claim what you haven't verified. This code is provided as an example and works great! If you are so sure that the code does not work, then try to reproduce, and justify your statement. This may not be the best practice, but I think the OP himself decided what to do with it.

Comment: @HarviDent I did verify it, that's the whole reason I posted the comment

Comment: No link to "undeclaredProperty" provided in the example. `$this->string` not even declared in the example so you're going to get an error thrown. Comments on the example are of no relevance if you don't update your post. Additionally, exposing someone without decent understanding of PHP to magic methods is not great.

Comment: @Rylee Sorry, but there will be no error here. When calling `$this->string`, we get into the __get magic method, which returns null. And this is one of the options for solving the OP's problem

Comment: @HarviDent if calling "undeclaredProperty" as a part of "__get" - you get stuck in a loop if the property you're looking for is not defined.

Comment: @Rylee And what does the `undeclaredProperty()` method have to do with it, it is declared and when called, the actions that are specified there will be performed.

Answer (score -2):

Have you thought about using namespaces and static methods instead?

You would have to change your auto-loading, but something like:

```php
// MyLibrary_Strings.php
namespace MyLibrary {
    class Strings {
        public static function mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding) {
            $firstChar = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $encoding);
            $then = mb_substr($string, 1, null, $encoding);
            return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
        }
    }
}

// MyLibrary_Arrays.php
namespace MyLibrary {
    class Arrays {
        public static function first($array) {
            return $array[0];
        }
    }
}

// some other code
$result = MyLibrary\String::mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding);
$first_item = MyLibrary\Array::first(["a", "b", "c"]);
```

Comment: Many (widely used) libraries use this format